# What changes can improve my visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image]

I am an Indian oil and petrol bunk dealer. I am travelling to UK and Europe in a tour package with my wife. I have started my business in Jan 2018. So I’m unable to refelect my proof of income in my ITR. Kindly suggest what else I can show to prove my income( i have stated my income has 1,60,000 INR per month).

Documents provided:

1. 6 months statement of credit, over draft and saving account bank statement.
2. 1lakh FD statement of my wife.
3. Invoice of purchase of fuel for 6 months
4. indian oil dealership agreement.
5. land documents

   6. Travel itinerary
   7. Flight tickets
   8. Hotel booking voucher 
      Kindly answer my question its not answerd before. Its not duplicate
      My question: If I giving CA documents along with my previous documents and fill application correctly next time. Will they find any new mistakes and reject the visa again?
      Pls answer me.

Comment: You should have some bank statements. Spending 2 month salary on 4 days is also suspicious (and I would add: they help you not to overspending).

Comment: I don't understand why starting your business in January 2018 would make you unable to show your income.

Comment: Chris H: My previous ITR show only income till March 2018. How else can I show income for past 9months. Can CA have any solution?

Comment: @Abhishek What is an ITR? Your tax return? You say that you own a business and that business pays you. Unless you are running your business very badly, with no clear financial separation between your money and the business's money, there must be documentary evidence that you have been paid. If you can prove your income to the Indian tax authorities, you can give the same proof for your visa application.

Comment: Honestly, though, I don't understand your visit plan. What are you planning on doing that will cost £3160 for just four days? That's a huge amount of money, especially to somebody who only claims to earn £1700 per month. You could probably stay in the UK for a month with that much money.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Cost of the tour will include cost of travel.

Comment: @DJClayworth I just asked Travelocity and it suggested that return flights from Mumbai (randomly chosen location in India) to London (any airport) on random days in April cost about £500-600 per person.

Comment: @David  it’s total cost of my trip for uk and europe for 20 days which include travel,food accommodation and everything.

Comment: @Abhishek Well, the visa officer clearly thought you intended to spend all of that money in four days in the UK. When you reapply, you need to make it clear how much you estimate you'll spend during your four days in the UK.

Comment: 1) If i give my father’s or father in law’s ITR,RTC of agriculture land will it helpful? 2) If i provide Clarification for all the 3 queries by visa officer will it be enough? Will they re consider my application and reject my application for any other new reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you have been refused, and what you can do to improve it are clearly stated in the refusal notice.

You have not provided any documentation that backs up your claim of income. You need to provide such documents. The obvious way to do it is to provide bank statements, preferably both for you and your company, showing your claimed income going out from your company and going in to your personal account. Documentation showing that the company is getting real income from outside sources would also help. These statements need to cover a substantial period of time, such as the last six months.

You also need to provide details of your expenditures, as stated in the refusal notice. Not providing these when you were asked to do so virtually guarantees rejection of the application.

Comment: Sometimes getting a chartered accountant to prepare certified documents showing an accurate financial picture is helpful in such situations. That said a business that started just last year doesn’t give a lot of confidence.